# Installing .NET 4 on Win XP gives error "ordinal could not be located in the dynamic link library msi.dll"

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

I have tried to download .NET 4.0 on Windows XP, and it won't work.

I need it for Sims Medieval and I have downloaded it 3 times. Each time I click it:

> the ordinal 254 could not be located in the dynamic link library msi.dll.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

What service pack are you on in Windows XP? Try updating to Service Pack 3, since .NET 4 [isn't supported on anything lower than that](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Windows XP SP2 will take .NET 4 just fine if you use the offline installer.

Comment: This answer is not wrong. According to the link XP SP3 is indeed the only **supported** version of XP for .NET 4. It may work on SP2, but that doesn't mean it's supported on SP2.

Comment: It wasn't wrong when .NET 4 first came out. What happened is SP2 itself is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your Windows installation is corrupted.  msi.dll is used for installing things in general.  You could try installing/reinstalling the latest version of "Windows Installer."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Windows Installer Service is not up to date. Make sure you install all the system updates. And as @Ray commented, it's best to start with SP3 - it may already contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have Windows Installer 3.1 installed yet.